# ViewSwitcher loading screen layout loads everytime MainActivity is opened

Tags: android, view

I am trying to display a loading screen for a time delay before my MainActivity opens. I am using a ViewSwitcher to first load the loading screen layout, and after the delay, it switches to the main layout. All this works fine.

The code in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
   new LoadViewTask().execute();
}

private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Void>{
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
  viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(MainActivity.this);
  viewSwitcher.addView(View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.loading_screen, null));

  loadImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.loadingLogo);
  setContentView(viewSwitcher);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... params){
  try{
     synchronized(this){
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter <=4 ){
        this.wait(850);
        counter++;
        }
      }
     }catch(InterruptedException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
 viewSwitcher.addView(View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main, null));
 viewSwitcher.showNext();
 initMainView();  //THIS INITIALIZES[SETS LISTENERS ETC] MY MAIN LAYOUT BUTTONS
}
}
```

The problem is that this activity launches several other activities for results, and when they return a result, I get a NullPointerException when I try to access any element within the activity_main layout. I found that the Activity is trying to load the Loading Screen everytime the activity is opened. How do I prevent this? How can I ensure the loading layout is only called once?

I tried this within onActivityResult of MainActivity

```
if(requestCode == 2){
 if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
   if(viewSwitcher.getDisplayedChild() == 0){
    Log.d(MTAG, " Inside view switcher is displaying child 0 ");
    viewSwitcher.showNext();
    initMainView();
   }
   continueButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION HERE
  }
}
```

But this is not working. I am still new to Android programming, so do try and explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of ViewSwitcher you can use `ProgressDialog` or `SplashScreen` to hold the view...

Comment: @SilentKiller Thanks for the response, I checked out SplashScreen and found a useful tutorial, and got it to work. The link - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App Even though this is not direct answer to my question, it led to a solution, so should I mark this as the answer? I am still new here, so please excuse the ignorance.

Comment: @mologish as i had just given a you a hint not given you answer so no need to accept.. if you still not finding any solution so i can help you anytime... :)

Comment: @SilentKiller Thanks for the response, but I did manage to figure this one out. :)